# Codeigniter Session is working on localhost but not on web server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to use session in my project. It works on localhost but not on web server. I read some articles about that in stackoverflow and ellislab, but it didn't work for my project. Probably problem is about creating ancillary classes.

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {

//protected $CI;

function __construct()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    parent::__construct();

    $CI->load->library('session');
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');
    //$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $CI->load->helper('date');
    $CI->load->helper('ip_address');
    $CI->load->model('Sql_model');
}
```

Now errors are :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Line Number: 14
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function library() on a non-object

Line Number: 14
```

Comment: Is that `controllers` directory or `libraries` directory class?

Comment: This class in controller directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->helper('ip_address');
    $this->load->model('Sql_model');
}
```

If class is in controllers directory, you can directly get the CI instance by extending the CI_Controller and use `$this`.

Comment: In the beginning I was trying that one but it is only working on localhost.

Comment: but this should help you in both localhost and live server, there is no need for this `$CI =& get_instance();` and using `$CI->`

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/ancillary_classes.html I read that article and I thought my problem is related with that guide

Comment: see the first line, `apart from controllers`.

Comment: Should I save every session to db?

Comment: When I use this-> load ... it is just refreshing the page. When I use $CI it is trying to reach login function.

Comment: keep exit and check where its missing to execute with `$this`.

Comment: I think if I missed $this .. in somewhere it wouldn't be working even on localhost

Comment: you have missed `$this`, try adding, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for errors...

Answer (score 0):

Than, try without calling get_instance() function. Just like docs says:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {

//protected $CI;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');
    //$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->helper('ip_address');
    $this->load->model('Sql_model');
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But session is not working when I used that. When I have started using $CI at least it is trying to reach login function in Sql_model

Answer (score 0):

This will make you crazy. but it works.

In **`autoload.php`**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','date','ip_address');
```

and **load model in `__constructor`**

```
public function  __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Sql_model');
}
```